# URGENCE Error cs0542 member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-c++, compiler-errors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Pokemon.Overworld
{
    public struct Location
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        public int Region;
        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        //public int Generation;
        public int[] Versions;
        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        public int Area;
        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        public Locations Location;
        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        public int MatrixId;
        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// Town, Route, Dungeon, Underground, Safari
        /// ToDo: C? P? W? Union? Direct?
        public int Type;
    }
}
```

I got this error and dont know how to resolve it.

> error CS0542: `Pokemon.Overworld.Location.Location': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
>   the error is at line 22,20

Comment: nobody ever tries to read exception messages :(

Answer (score 0):

the error is pretty descriptive. You have a property as

`public Locations Location;`

and your struct name is also

```
public struct Location
```

Change the property `Location` to `Locations` and it should work. But more important is, you should understand **why**.